# The <h1> title in Reopen queue's revision revies made me think OP is abusing markup

Tags: discussion, review

It took me a while till I realized what I see is question title, not markup abuse:

[image: image description]

Since new users are known for placing unnecessary **bold**,

- lists

and

### headings

in their posts I actually navigated to the post to edit that out. Even now that I know what I'm looking at, it's confusing.

Comment: And? Is there a point to this?

Comment: Yeah I think it should be changed so it's consistent with, for example, suggested edits view.